# Custom Navbar Dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm wanting to implement something similar to following dropdown feature on my website, however I have limited skills in this area. Is there a css library I can use to get the desired result? Or will I have to manually create this myself?
Any examples would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use BootStrap's Dropdowns. It supports images inside the text area. Overwrite the CSS so that it looks similar to the dropdown in the image. This way you won't need to rewrite everything.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/